# SimpleAdapter showing an empty list

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

The code is compile without errors, but the result is just an empty list on my phone. So what is the problem? Here is my onCreate method in Activity

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView textView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> m;
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        m=new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put("key", "value"+i);
        list.add(m);
    }
    String[] from={"key"};
    int[] to={R.id.text1};
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    SimpleAdapter sa=new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.row, from, to);        
    lv.setAdapter(sa);
```

main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/text1"
              android:text="dddddddd"
            />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think it might have to do with your using match_parent and fill_parent everywhere rather than wrap_content...?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good, do you mean to use everywhere wrap_content in layout sizes? or what? i tried it, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `row.xml`, change

```
<TextView android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

A width of `0px` will make the view invisible and should only be used in conjunction with `layout_weight`

Comment: Oh God, thank you, i just used previously 0px becouse i used it with layout_weight, but now i forgot that there is no other elements here to use weight